# how to make modify form for list of entity in symfony

Tags: symfony

I use symfony2 framework and i have a template which shows a list of entities   (for example my products ) i would like to create a single form to delete , activate/inactivate and some other actions in the lists , actually i have done it before but on that occasion i created some action(for example toggleActiveAction(Product $product)) without the use of a form, just by creating a link but i think in this approach i am in danger of Cross-site request forgery attacks,someone has suggested to create a form for each entity but i think it isn't a good way, how can i handle this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then come back and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * 
 * @Route("/news/update/{id}", name="news_update")
 */
public function updateAction(Request $request, $id) {
        //Here I call my service
        $newsService = $this->get('app.news_service');

        //Here I receive the Entity I want to edit
        $toUpdate = $newsService->fetchById($id);

        //Here I create the form that I have defined in AppBundle\Forms
        $form = $this->createForm(new NewsForm(), $toUpdate);


        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            //Once the form is submitted my newsService updates the Entity in the database.
            $newsService->update($toUpdate);

            //I redirect overview
            return $this->redirectToRoute('news_show', array(), 301);
        }

        return $this->render('default/news/updateNews.html.twig', array(
                    'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . '/..'),
                    'form' => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }
```

This would first bring you to a form which the user submits to save the changes.

Comment: it's not what i want. imagine you have a table with 10 rows to show your news and you need delete and active/inactive button in front of each of them how can you do that?!do you create 10 form with appropriate button for each news?!

Comment: No, you create 2 forms. They receive the ID of the product and perform the desired action.
That is delete, or activate de activate. Idealy you dont use forms, you simply use a service which you use in the controller.

Comment: i think this is what i want , would u mind explaning a bit more(please show me your service and your view)

Comment: Ok, let's say you have a table where the table elements have the following form:

|el.prop1|el.prop2|el.prop3|el.prop4|el.prop5|{{<link to switch activationAction*>}}|{{<link to deleteAction*>}}
In both of these actions you pass the element ID like this: 
    {{ path('controller_name', { 'id': el.id }) }}

Now in the controller 'controller_name' you either call a service that deltes the element, or using the get and set methods of your element class, you change it in the controller itself (although this is not the best practice).

Comment: i think you haven't understood what i mean.i could do this but it's in danger of CSRF attacks.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/book/forms.html#csrf-protection

Instead of using the links, use submit buttons, where the id value and the type of action is passed, symfony does the rest. Sorry for not understanding your question correctly :) On the link in the top there is the info you are looking for.

Comment: sorry dude , i don't understand what you mean , could you explain a bit more!?

Comment: So you can have more than one submit button for your form. You can make one for each of the items in your list, and give them a value related to the id of the element. F. e.: <td><input type="submit" value="{{ item.id }}-s" label="hallo"/></td>
Make the form surrounds the table of the items you are showing, and use a foreach to add the submits. Also pass all the item id's beig shown.
In your controller then you generate all the possible submit values and check them with isClicked(), once you found the one having been clicked you act accordingly. F. e.: 5-d means you delete the item with id=5

Comment: thank you dude , i think it'll work :)) but in this time i have to take part in code competition and i can't use your trick! but for last question how can i change action path of the form to be like this(/news/update/{id})

Comment: You do it in the controller. As you see in my controller, in the comment in the @Route part. You can also place a default there.

By the way another way to do what you wanted to would be to redirect to a page with a form where you confirm your action, or if you make the form "appear" next to the table and pass it what ever value you want with javascript. After which you confirm.

This is I think in the end a better solution, since it shouldn't be as processing intensive as my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

use the same structure you use to show a list.
To show active products in the view you can use:

`{% if product.active %}
{{ product.attribute }} //It will put the products attribute in the browser if it is active
{%endif%}`

Here twig checks if product.active ==(=) true.
You can use it in a for loop to loop through al the products.

```
{% for product in products %}
//The if block could go here.
{% enfor %}
```

Comment: i think you don't understand what i mean, i need a single form which can modify each entity lonely.for example i want to show 10 products and each product has some button for active ,inactive , delete or some thing else.i can create 10 form for them but i think its wrong